# Get null key with JSONArray values from JSON Object

Tags: android, arrays, json

Can anyone one help me to get null key value from this JSON Object?

'null' is the JSONArray, I want to iterate and get the values from it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlVrt.png

Comment: show the structure of the JSON you are receiving please

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlVrt.png

Comment: That does not show me why the key is null. How is it being created?

Comment: It's from the different project not sure how it's been created. I want to know how to read the null key values.

Comment: Please post  json  as text.

Comment: If you do this `results.getJSONArray("data")` what does it return?

Comment: @joao86 its returns JSONArray, but since here the key is null. It was throwing null pointer

Answer (score 1):

here your parser

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject results=object.getJSONObject("results");
    JSONObject data=results.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray array=data.getJSONArray("null");
    for (int i=0;i<=array.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject temp=array.getJSONObject(i);
        String score=temp.getString("score");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Is it a right way to give key as null?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use opt or getJsonArray on your JSON results

```
for (int i = 0; i<results.optJSONArray("data").length();i++){
    JSONObject json = <results.optJSONArray("data").get(i);
    int score = json.optInt("score");
    String id = json.optString("id");
    etc..

}
```

This will iterate on your data and extract infos

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference